Fast static vector implementation in Python
Consider the following two naive implementations of 3D static vectors in Python:
class Vec1(tuple):
    def __new__(c,x,y,z):
        return super().__new__(c,(x,y,z))
    def __add__(s,o):
        return s.__class__(s[0]+o[0],s[1]+o[1],s[2]+o[2])
    def __matmul__(s,o):
        return s[0]*o[0]+s[1]*o[1]+s[2]*o[2]
class Vec2:
    def __init__(s,x,y,z):
        s.c=(x,y,z)
    def __add__(s,o):
        sc=s.c
        oc=o.c
        return Vec2(sc[0]+oc[0],sc[1]+oc[1],sc[2]+oc[2])
    def __matmul__(s,o):
        sc=s.c
        oc=o.c
        return sc[0]*oc[0]+sc[1]*oc[1]+sc[2]*oc[2]

A clean implementation is Vec1 which inherits methods from tuple. However, the initialization of Vec1 (and, consequently, addition __add__) is 1.5 times slower than that of Vec2 (on my machine). I suppose, the reason for this is the call of tuple.__new__(). I'm aware that the initialization is still very fast (a fraction of a microsecond) and that I can improve the performance using Cython, Numba, or PyPy. But I'm interested in the question of how far I can get without using any third-party modules. Is it possible to initialize a Vec1 instance some other way? E.g. by directly writing to the memory location of the tuple elements?

@JérômeRichard I'd like to avoid writing a C extension for now. In Vec2.__new__ a tuple is also created but without any type checking. Is it impossible then to access and write to the memory location of the tuple elements in Vec1.__new__? Or to disable this type checking in the call of tuple.__new__?

You could try another version using __slots__, which has good performance. Just inherit from object, set the class' slots, and measure the perf.

@Lenormju yes, thank you. __slots__ can improve performance slightly.

@JérômeRichard wrote a lot of good comments yesterday. But for some reasons he removed all of them.
